# can typescript do union type assertion in this case?

Tags: typescript, types, union-types

can typescript do union type assertion in this case ? i want to use `ab.a` or `ab.b` or `ab. hasOwnProperty` to do assertion of `type A` or `type B` ? how do i do ?

```
export interface A extends Object {
    a: string;
}

export interface B extends Object {
    b: number;
}

export type AorB = A | B;

function test(ab: AorB) {
    // can ts auto predict this ?
    if (ab.hasOwnProperty('a')) {
        ab.a // type error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your function as below:

```
function test(ab: AorB) {
    // can ts auto predict this ?
    if ('a' in ab) {
        console.log(ab.a);
    }
}
```